# Soap returning a HTTP request failed error

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm getting this error when trying to open a WSDL but I've also tested other valid HTPP address and I'm getting the same error.

Could this be something in my php.ini configuration?  I have checked `allow_url_fopen` and that is set to on.  here is the exact error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CURL instead of traditional file functions. This will also allow to debug you connection errors better.

Answer (score 0):

try using [fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/), so you can view all the raw content of your requests and responses